# PostgreSQL Install on Linux error - edb does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Brand new installation of Postgres Plus Advanced Server 9.1 on a Linux VM.  I've now installed it twice and I have the same problem.  When I open up the Postgres Enterprise Manager and right-click on the "Postgres Plus Advanced Server 9.1" (which has a red X on it) and click on "Connect", I key in the password and then I get the error message:

> An error has occurred: Error connecting to the server: FATAL: database "edb" does not exist

I'm lost - I've searched and searched and can't find any good solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem.  When I installed my Postgres server, I installed it in "Postgres" mode.  Therefore, when I go into Postgres Enterprise Manager, I had to change the maintenance database to "Postgres" instead of "edb".  Once I did that, everything worked great!

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to change the referenced database on your pgAdmin. To do that just double click on "Maintenance Database" and point it to postgres